# Need to Add two varibles under same value in array

Tags: php, arrays, session, addition

I have a cart system that uses `array_push` to add cart items to cart.  The problem is that it doesn't add price of the item to array.  How can I get it to add:

```
Item - ItemPrice
Item_2 - ItemPrice_2
Item_3 - ItemPrice_3
```

as a set.  Not as a separate items

```
Item
ItemPrice
Item_2
ItemPrice_2
Item_3
ItemPrice_3
```

my code to add it is this:

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'],'Item_2');
```

Is there a way to add a price with this Item_2

Edit: or maybe I should do

```
itemName -> item_1, item_2, item_3              itemPrice -> itemPrice_1, itemPrice_2, itemPrice_3
```

but I wouldn't know how to make this coded correctly.
I also call for this in a table at My Cart page like this:

```
$array = $_SESSION['cart'];
echo "<table class=cart>";     
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    echo "<tr><td><p>" . $key . "</p></td><td><p>" . $value . "</p></td><td><p><a href=#>Remove?</a></p></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Why not push an array onto the cart? `array_push($_SESSION['cart'],array('Item_2' => 'price'));`, or somesuch?

Comment: @andrewsi I did that and now it's giving me and error  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\xxxxxxxx on line 15"

Comment: line 15 is "array_push($_SESSION['cart'],'itemName' => '13.99'); // "

Comment: You need to wrap it in an `array()`, too.

Comment: @andrewsi thanks but the other guys solution works better. But thanks anyway God Bless You.

Comment: No problem at all; you use whatever works best for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just assign the price as the value and the name as the key of the array, so:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][item] = item_price;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array('item' => 'itemName', 'price' => 'itemPrice');

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $array) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $array['item'] . "</td><td>" . $array['price] . "</td><td><a href="#">Remove?</a></td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work the solution from Luke works better. Thanks anyway. God Bless You.